# Get the SUM of file sizes within in an EXCEL Worksheet from a Dynamic Column using VBScript

Tags: excel, vbscript, sum

I have a VBScript which counts all the MSI's I have in a folder, and outputs the information to an excel sheet which displays 4 columns A = MSI NAME, B = Filesize, C = Created Date, D = Path. At the very end in the last empty row, after the iteration there are two more pieces of information outputted. 1st Total Packages which I just used a simple counter for this works for what I need, 2nd Total File Size which is what I'm trying to accomplish here. I need the script to start from `B2` until the second to last row because the last row will contain that 2nd outputted piece of information "Total File Size:123gb". The rows are dynamic so as more MSI's are created this list will grow. Here's the code I've gotten so far. No matter what I do Total File Size is always 0. Thanks in advance!

Excel.VBS

```
Option Explicit 'force all variables to be declared
Dim msiName, msiSize, msiCreated, msiPath, msiCount, Suffix
Dim objFSO
Dim objWorksheet
Dim objExcel
Dim objWorkbook
Dim intRow
Dim ch

Const ForWriting = 2
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Visible = true
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Add()
Set objWorksheet = objWorkbook.Worksheets(1)


Recurse objFSO.GetFolder("Z:\")

Dim lastRowB, fileSizeTotal, objFileSizeSum
objFileSizeSum = objWorksheet.Range("B2:B744")
fileSizeTotal = objExcel.WorksheetFunction.Sum(objFileSizeSum)
lastRowB = objWorksheet.Range("B65536").End(-4162).Row + 1
objExcel.Cells(lastRowB, 2) = "Total File Size: " & fileSizeTotal

objExcel.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit


MsgBox ("Complete")

intRow = 2
msiCount = 0

Sub Recurse(objFolder)
    Dim objFile, objSubFolder
    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
        If LCase(objFSO.GetExtensionName(objFile.Name)) = "msi" Then
            objExcel.Cells(1,1) = "MSI Name"
            objExcel.Cells(1,2) = "MSI Size"
            objExcel.Cells(1,3) = "Created Date"
            objExcel.Cells(1,4) = "File Path"

            msiName = objFile.Name
            msiSize = ConvertSize(objFile.Size)
            msiCreated = objFile.DateCreated
            msiPath = objFile.ParentFolder

            intRow = intRow + 1
            objExcel.Cells(intRow, 1).Value = msiName
            objExcel.Cells(intRow, 2).Value = msiSize
            objExcel.Cells(intRow, 3).Value = msiCreated
            objExcel.Cells(intRow, 4).Value = msiPath

            msiCount = msiCount + 1

            Dim lastRowA
            lastRowA = objWorksheet.Range("A65536").End(-4162).Row + 1
            objExcel.Cells(lastRowA, 1) = "Total Packages: " & msiCount - 1 

            objExcel.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit

        End If
    Next

    For Each objSubFolder In objFolder.SubFolders
        Recurse objSubFolder
    Next
End Sub

Function ConvertSize(Size)
Do While InStr(Size,",") 'Remove commas from size
    CommaLocate = InStr(Size,",")
    Size = Mid(Size,1,CommaLocate - 1) & _
        Mid(Size,CommaLocate + 1,Len(Size) - CommaLocate)
Loop

Suffix = " Bytes"
If Size >= 1024 Then suffix = " KB"
If Size >= 1048576 Then suffix = " MB"
If Size >= 1073741824 Then suffix = " GB"
If Size >= 1099511627776 Then suffix = " TB"

Select Case Suffix
    Case " KB" Size = Round(Size / 1024, 1)
    Case " MB" Size = Round(Size / 1048576, 1)
    Case " GB" Size = Round(Size / 1073741824, 1)
    Case " TB" Size = Round(Size / 1099511627776, 1)
End Select

ConvertSize = Size & Suffix
End Function
```

Sample Output

```
MSI_2_02_002.msi    24.8 MB 10/7/2019    11:23  Z:\Xyz
MSI_1_1.msi         439 KB  11/6/2019    13:10  Z:\Xyz
MSI_S_1_1.msi       439 KB  11/18/2019   12:12  Z:\Xyz
Total Packages: 743 Total File Size: 0
```

Comment: Create a Public variable, and then inside your loop, keep updating it which each new file. Something like `TotalSize=TotalSize+objFile.Size`. LAter on, on your main sub, you could add something like `objExcel.Cells(lastRowB, 2)=ConvertSize(TotalSize)`

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns AMAZING! It worked please list as the answer so I can accept it! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have already designed your codes in two different procedures, I think the easiest way is using a Public Variable.

You can create a Public variable at the top of your mode, something like this:

`Public TotalSize`

Then, in your procedure `Sub Recurse(objFolder)`, inside your `For..Next` I would add:

`TotalSize=TotalSize+objFile.Size`

So at the end of the loop, variable `TotalSize` will be your grand total.

Second step will be calling that grand total into your main sub, with a line like:

`objExcel.Cells(lastRowB, 2)=ConvertSize(TotalSize)`.

The reason your first approach was not working, it's because your output is a string, according to your code. You were getting:

```
24.8 MB
439 KB
439 KB
```

Because there is text in these cells, you can't sum them (as far as I know, you can sum only numbers).

Comment: They're using VBScript not VB, VBA or VB.Net so the only option is `Variant` data types.